# iOS : OpenGL 2.0 ES moving around an object

Tags: ios, 3d, opengl-es-2.0

So, I am trying to port my openGLES 1.0 code to OpenGLES 2.0 (GLKit).  Basic concept is you can walk around in 3D space.

What I am struggling with is moving around an object based on my camera position (got controls wired up etc)

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    self.baseEffect.transform.modelviewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt(eye[0], eye[1], eye[2],center[0],  center[1], center[2], 0.0, 1, 0.0);
    [self.baseEffect prepareToDraw];

    self.cube.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = self.baseEffect.transform.modelviewMatrix;
    self.cube.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = self.baseEffect.transform.projectionMatrix;

    // Used to scale stuff based on screen res
    static float roation = 0;
    self.cube.rotation =  GLKVector3Make(0, roation, 0);
    [self.cube drawWithRotationWithRenderMode:RenderTexture];

    [self handleTouches];
}
```

The bit I am stuck with is the render of the cube based on camera (I believe I need something like setIdentyM

```
- (void)drawWithRotationWithRenderMode:(RenderMode)renderMode
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:APP_DELEGATE.context];

    float alpha = 1;
    float doNotRender = NO;

    GLKMatrix4 current = GLKMatrix4Identity;
    current = GLKMatrix4Translate(current, position.x, position.y, position.z);
    current = GLKMatrix4Scale(current, scale.x, scale.y, scale.z);
    self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = current;
```

Comment: So I think my camera is working I just need to know how to put the object at a X,y,z I believe.  How similar are the Android OpenGL calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue where baseEffect was not init before it was being used :(